# Подключение базы на Oracle Java

Tags: oracle, java

Как подключить базу на Oracle к программе на Java в NetBeans

Answer (score 2):

Выкачиваешь какой-нибудь [JDBC драйвер для Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html). Из там 2 (родных), один тонкий (JDBC thin) на чистой Java, второй через OCI (JDBC-OCI) с нативными вставками (побыстрее, но по-моему требует OCI клиента на вашей стороне).

Далее строго [по инструкциям](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html)

**Update**

1. JDBC-OCI точно требует установки клиента на вашей стороне.
2. Неплохие инструкции по обоим драйверам [здесь](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)