# библиотека для подключения в Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Есть БД Oracle.. нужно написать программу на java. Как можно подключиться к oracle? А точнее какие есть библиотеки jdbc?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключение базы на Oracle Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/324357/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-oracle-java)

Answer (score 3):

если программа простая, то можно скачать [jdbc driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html) и подключить как библиотеку, если же используется сборщик maven, gradle, etc то можно [подключить драйвер как зависимость](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides)

для начала (а раз вы спрашиваете как подключить, то это скорее всего начало :) ) должно хватить `ojdbc8.jar`

Описание дополнительных библиотек есть в первой ссылке. Если вы считаете, что базового драйвера будет не достаточно, уточните требования к программе.

Comment: Да, это начало.. В программе нужно выводить в TableView данные из таблиц, записывать изменения в БД, добавлять и удалять записи..

ojdbc8.jar - это я так понимаю самый простой драйвер для мелких программ. А другие драйвера для чего используются? Что должна делать программа чтобы использовать другие драйвера?